# Spring boot app runs fine standalone, errs in docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot based java application which runs fine from the command line (embedded tomcat standalone).

**Problem**

When I run the app in docker, it does not run correctly. The console shows the application starts up fine with no errors; however, the browser displays the following error page:

> Whitelabel Error Page
>
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.

[I understand the message says no mapping for '/error' url. However I want to know the root cause ]

**Additional Info/Context**

- Spring boot 1.4.2
- docker plugin
- Output is 'war' file which also runs standalone
- I run docker image in 'host' networking mode (--net=host) so it can access the database (mysql running on my localhost)

**build.gradle target**

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  push = false
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from war
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD floss.war app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

**Command to Run Docker**

```
dockerImg=1248c47d9cfa
docker run \
       -it \
       --net=host \
       -e SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON="$SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON" \
       $dockerImg
```

I'm new to docker and would appreciate any suggestions.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you run ```docker ps```, then ```docker logs --tail 100 -f ${YOUR_CONTAINER_ID}``` to see if there's any stacktrace shown in stdout/stderr when the error occurred?

Answer (score 3):

Problems:

1. No exposed port in dockerfile
2. No port mapping with host.

Sol:
1. expose application port in dockerfile and build image

`EXPOSE $application_port`

2. then run

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -d -e SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON="$SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON" $dockerImg`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. You seem to be using the same Docker example for Spring Boot as I was. As you can see, the WAR file gets a .jar extension when it is placed into the Docker image, not .war.

I was able to solve the issue by calling the file "app.war" instead of "app.jar" and changing the Java startup parameters accordingly.

If you use the extension ".jar", the access to static resources works fine, but accessing all dynamic content (JSPs, ...) leads to a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

i suspect it is due to the missing -p option, can you try this. change the port if it is different.
docker run -p 8080:8080
       -it \
       --net=host \
       -e SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON="$SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON" \
       $dockerImg