# Dockerized Java app dies with no error message but runs fine standalone

Tags: java, docker

**Please note:** I *know* this questions is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579320/spring-boot-app-runs-fine-standalone-errs-in-docker) however you'll note that the solution in that case was to `EXPOSE` the port, which I am already doing. Hence although this questions *sounds* similar, I think its simply a different problem altogether with similar *symptoms* as the other question.

---

Docker Version 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995) here. I am experimenting with Docker for the first time and have built my first Docker image. My `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN mkdir /opt/myapp

ADD build/libs/myapp.jar /opt/myapp
ADD application.yml /opt/myapp
ADD logback.groovy /opt/myapp
WORKDIR /opt/myapp
EXPOSE 9200
ENTRYPOINT java -Dspring.config=. -jar myapp.jar
```

I build it via:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

Everything succeeds. I then tag it as if I'm going to push it to Quay:

```
docker tag <imageId> quay.io/myregistry/myapp:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

However before I publish to Quay I want to run it locally to make sure it works:

```
docker run -it -p 9200:9200 -d --env-file /Users/myuser/myapp-local.env --name myapp myapp
```

When I run this I get an indication that the container is running, and I can even see it for a few seconds via `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f3fa8f7a4288        myapp               "/bin/sh -c 'java -D…"   Less than a second ago   Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp   myapp
```

However after a few seconds it stops running and disappears from `docker ps` altogether:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
```

Furthermore I'm not able to SSH into the container:

```
docker exec -it f3fa8f7a4288 bash
Error: No such container: f3fa8f7a4288
```

...or see any logs/console output.

When I run `myapp.jar` outside of Docker (as a typical Spring Boot app, it starts up and runs beautifully without exceptions). **How can I troubleshoot what is going on?**

Comment: Do you specify how much memory your JVM is allowed to use? How much RAM does the docker give the container running the jvm? If the jvm uses more memory than its container has available it simply gets killed without warning.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 (+1) correct me if I'm wrong but if you don't specify the amount of RAM to use for the JVM, then Java will allow itself to consume (potentially) **all** the available system RAM. Since I can run this on my laptop *outside* of Docker without any problems, I would expect the Dockerized JVM to do the same (unless my Docker config is throttling the container memory to a certain size...), right?

Comment: You should be able to run `docker logs {container id}` even for a container that has shut down. What output is there?

Comment: Kind of correct, the problem is that the JVM determines the memory incorrectly and knows your system memory, not the docker container memory - say your system has 4gb ram, your docker container has 1gb, the jvm (even in the docker container) sees 4gb and does not worry about running the gc early. As soon as it hits 1gb of ram it gets killed. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere! A few things: **(1)** I ran `docker logs` and was able to see its actually my Spring Boot app being unable to connect to MySQL running locally. I'll troubleshoot from here and will post a separate question if need be, so thanks! **(2)** Since the crux of my question was "how do I troubleshoot", if you would like to convert your comments into a recommendation to use `docker logs` I'll happily give you the check! **(3)** Also, even though RAM wasn't the culprit here I'm curious as to how to configure Docker/JVM RAM so this doesn't bite me some day...any ideas?

Comment: Try running it without `-d` and you will get the output right into your stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command will show you the output a container is generating when you run it detached (with `-d`). This is likely to include the error message.

```
docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps container
```

You can run the image in the foreground without the `-d` to see the output like when you run myapp.jar outside of Docker.

```
docker run my/image
```

So in this specific case:

```
docker run -it -p 9200:9200 --env-file /Users/myuser/myapp-local.env --name myapp myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, the issue you are experiencing is because you are using the *shell* form of `ENTRYPOINT`. Change it to use the *exec* version, as follows:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.config=.", "-jar", "myapp.jar"]
```

The shell form will launch Java as a separate process just like a shell command. This causes PID 1 to return making Docker believe the container is finished. Using the exec form, the Java process replaces PID 1 and the container will continue running.

Comment: Thanks @Frelling (+1) the issue seems to be network-related (my app can't talk to a MySQL DB) but I appreciate the tip about using the exec form!